# Resize text simultaneously while resizing textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to resize text simultaneously while resizing the textarea. Below is my code. Below is my jQuery. I guess the issue is to do with the click function been seperated? Not sure though. I'd like some advice in fixing this please.

JsFiddle: (did not allow to post the JsFidde so here it is
http: // jsfiddle.net / mr_eirenaios/Tr92Q/8/)

```
$("#aTx").click(function () {
    $("#DVtx").append('<textarea rows="3" id="aText">Type Here</textarea>');
});
var diagonalScl;
var txSiz;
$(function () {
    $("#DVtx").resizable({
        alsoResize: '#aText',
        create: function (event, ui) {
            diagonalScl = diagonalSwItms();
            txSiz = parseInt($("#aText").css("font-size"));
        },
        resize: function (e, ui) {
            var diagonalSclNw = diagonalSwItms();
            var ratio = diagonalSclNw / diagonalScl;
            $("#aText").css("font-size", txSiz + ratio * 3);
        }
    });
});

function diagonalSwItms() {
    var contentWidth = $("#aText").width();
    var contentHeght = $("#aText").height();
    return contentWidth * contentWidth + contentHeght * contentHeght;
}
```

Comment: title does not match with the problem statement :-|

Comment: @Harry - The OP seems to be trying to change the font size when the textarea is resized.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: Agree and Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it in a new fiddle check out this http://jsfiddle.net/u5LUe/1/ i have used the `stop event on the resizing element` and i find that the calculation that you are using for the font size returns a big value and it is not correct so do some other calculation for the font size and do the small change in the code

Answer (score 1):

[FlowType.js](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/) is all you need, like love for Beatles.

Comment: Thank you!! :) I'd rather want to see what's wrong and fix my code.